# php cant define mssql_connect function

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to make a connection between PHP and a SQL server's database. I'm running XAMPP, and I deleted the `;` from `extension=php_mssql.dll` to enable the PHP extension by modifying the `php.ini` file.

When I run my script, however, PHP throws an error that says the function `mssql_connect()` doesn't exist.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: remember to run php_info() to test your php.ini file.  Many times people edit the wrong php.ini

Comment: Did you restart php after editing the php.ini?

Comment: What version of PHP? Look at [this article](http://forums.iis.net/t/1161224.aspx).

Comment: all done the problem was i delete ; and try to use mssql_connect without do restart for apache tx all

Answer (score 1):

So far xampp comes with MySQL and have not include Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL)

Comment: i knowww that but the function dosent run php give me error mssql_connect is unknown function

Comment: Latest xampp comes with php 5.3.5 and as I say mssql is not included http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php

Answer (score 0):

As a general approach:

In the php.ini is an option

```
display_startup_errors = Off
```

Set that to On and call PHP (maybe from console).
It should tell you what went wrong then.